# How can I choose by keyboard the autocorrect suggestions?

Tags: keyboard, messages

I love the **apple magic trackpad** but, I don't like to use mouse to chose something while I'm typing.

[image: autocomplete suggestion]

Is there a way, to pick the option using the keyboard?

PS: Note that sometimes it may exist more than one option to pick

[image: autocomplete multiple suggestions]

Comment: does pressing UP Arrow on the keyboard helps? (If suggestion appears on the bottom, try DOWN Arrow). Later You can choose words with LEFT/RIGHT Arrow. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the autocorrect suggestion is showing, you need to press the DOWN key, then you can use left and right to select if there is multiple. After that hit return. No mouse/trackpad interaction required. :)